# Overwrite Dlog4j.configuration Java argument

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

I am using a Weblogic server and have -Dlog4j.configuration argument set in server start up with a common path for the deployed applications. However, for a new application I want to set a different path and ignore this argument. As such I added:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfig</param-name>
  <param-value>META-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to web.xml file, which did not overwritte my argument. Is there a way to overwrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the **log4j.properties (or log4j.xml)** file needs to be included into Weblogic classpath; thus, supposing that you have placed it into the folder “C:\Weblogic\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config”, then you need adding this directory into the server Classpath text item.

The following log4j.properties defines a RollingFileAppender which will write logs to your domain root directory:(C:\Weblogic\user_projects\domains\base_domain)

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=mylog.log

log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=2MB

log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=2

log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger = INFO, rollingFile
```

Last effort, since WebLogic Server does not load any Log4j library in your domain, will be to include log4j in the `DOMAIN_HOME/lib` subdirectory. Place there a Log4j implementation (`log4j-X.X.X`) and Weblogic’s Log4j libraries (`wllog4j.jar`) which are part of the server distribution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm I have a prefer-application-packages set for a log4j lib in my project. I'm trying to use the log4j.configuration inside my new project while keeping the the common 'C:\Weblogic\user_projects\domains\base_domain' for the other deployed applications. When I change the argument to -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties it uses the my new application's log4j configuration, but the other applications don't have a log4j.properties file.

Comment: @Lequiv Okay. I assume you need to have separate log files for the project running inside same container with common config file for log4j. If really needed, you can have separate loggers defined in one log4j configuration, but that has to be supported by your application, which has to be able to pick up the correct logger. Then use `log4j.appender.File.File=/location/nameLogFile.log` to specify the file name.

Comment: The problem I found with a common configuration file is for common dependencies among different applications. I can set different appenders for my applications and even for their libraries, but if many applications have a common quite used and verbose dependency, it becomes hard to debug. I don't think it escalates well and root logger becomes illegible.

Comment: @Lequiv Yes. you are correct. I would suggest to have separate loggers/appenders defined in your log4j configuration.

Comment: so the only way is for all applications to heave their specific log? Can't I have it both ways? Some sharing a configuration using the -Dlog4j.configuration=C:\Weblogic\user_projects\domains\base_domain\log4j.properties in server start up arguments and others overwritting that argument to set the path to their own log4j.properties file?

Comment: no, you cannot have mixed configuration files by default. Log4j uses the first configuration file that finds and use from there. Some hybrid (not recommended) solutions can be done using custom classes). In particular  -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties has the highest priority